# Projection on C*-Algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, noncommutative-geometry

I am trying to show that if A is an arbitrary C*-algebra, $p$ is a projection if and only if $p^{*}p = p$. Now since the C*-algebra is arbitrary, we only have a norm and not necessarily an inner product, and I do not know how I can use the adjoint in this setting. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: What's your definition of a projection in a $C^*$ setting? The one I know is $p=p^{*}=p^2$.

Comment: A C*-homomorphism with $p^2 = p$, I think.

Comment: The word projection is usually used for _elements_ of a $C^*$ algebra, not for morphisms of it. What exactly are you looking at?

Comment: You are right, it seems to refer to elements of an arbitrary C*-algebra

Comment: Regarding the second sentence of the question - every C$^*$-algebra has a faithful representation on a Hilbert space, so if you proved $p$ is a projection iff $p^*p = p$ for operators on a Hilbert space, this would prove it for elements of an arbitrary C$^*$-algebra. Often it is easier to give direct algebraic proofs, though, as Aweygan did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity $p^*p=p$ implies
$$p^*=(p^*p)^*=p^*p=p,$$
and thus
$$p=p^*p=p^2$$